# sqlplus / as sysdba command not working in 12c

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle12c

sqlplus / as sysdba in not working with 12c

getting error ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

connection establishing only when provided username and password manually.

Comment: I think your DB is constructed as multitenant, and for this reason need to include username(`sys`) and pasword explicitly in contrast to a single instance database( for which using `sqlplus / as sysdba` is enough ).

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan how can i make it a single instance database

Comment: you need to reinstall from the beginning by choosing the option "single instance" from the wizard. There're plenty of videos through the net for these installations.